# Error OSError: Error no file named pytorch_model.bin in directory /repository llama2 on inference endpoints of hugging face

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

Im using hugging face inference endpoints with a fine-tunned llama2 using a AutoModelForSequenceClassification head. And getting this error:

```
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ raise EnvironmentError(
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2474, in from_pretrained
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ Traceback (most recent call last):
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 493, in from_pretrained
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/repository/handler.py", line 21, in __init__
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/app/huggingface_inference_toolkit/utils.py", line 190, in check_and_register_custom_pipeline_from_directory
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
qd28v 2023-12-05T14:07:39.184Z
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/app/huggingface_inference_toolkit/handler.py", line 41, in get_inference_handler_either_custom_or_default_handler
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ inference_handler = get_inference_handler_either_custom_or_default_handler(HF_MODEL_DIR, task=HF_TASK)
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ await handler()
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 682, in startup
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 584, in __aenter__
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ OSError: Error no file named pytorch_model.bin, tf_model.h5, model.ckpt.index or flax_model.msgpack found in directory /repository.
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ return model_class.from_pretrained(
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ custom_pipeline = handler.EndpointHandler(model_dir)
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ custom_pipeline = check_and_register_custom_pipeline_from_directory(model_dir)
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ File "/app/webservice_starlette.py", line 57, in some_startup_task
2023/12/05 15:07:39 ~ await self._router.startup()
```

Interestingly enough it works fine in the notebook.
My current hypothesis is that the inference endpoint backend assumes it to be a pytorch model than fails.
Still is quite tricky to debug it. Any suggestions?